# pygame fails to generate chess grid, not sure of error origin

Tags: python, pygame

for the project, I am at the point where I am currently drawing a board, I have the pygame window however, the squares will not draw over the screenfill command, I have tried getting rid of the command, changing colours but I don't know why the squares just won't draw in the window. Any help would be appreciated

````
import pygame as p
import chessEngine

p.init()
WIDTH = HEIGHT = 512  #400 is another option
DIMENSION = 8 #dimensions of a chess board are 8x8
SQ_SIZE = HEIGHT//DIMENSION
MAX_FPS = 30 #for animations
IMAGES = {}

def loadImages():
    pieces = ['wp','wR','wN','wB','wK','wQ','bp','bR','bN','bB','bK','bQ']
    for piece in pieces:
        IMAGES[piece] = p.transform.scale(p.image.load("images/" + piece + ".png"), (SQ_SIZE, SQ_SIZE))
    #Note: we can access an image by saying 'IMAGES['wp']'

def main():
    p.init()
    screen = p.display.set_mode((WIDTH, HEIGHT))
    clock = p.time.Clock()
    screen.fill(p.Color("white"))
    gs = chessEngine.GameState()
    loadImages()
    running = True
    while running:
        for e in p.event.get():
            if e.type == p.QUIT:
                running = False
        clock.tick(MAX_FPS)
        p.display.flip()

def drawGameState(screen, gs):
    drawBoard(screen)
    drawPieces(screen, gs.board)

def drawBoard(screen):
    colors = [p.Color("white"), p.Color("gray")]
    for r in range(DIMENSION):
        for c in range(DIMENSION):
            color = colors[((r+c) % 2)]
            p.draw.rect(screen, color, p.Rect(c*SQ_SIZE, r*SQ_SIZE, SQ_SIZE, SQ_SIZE)) 


def drawPieces(screen, board):
    pass

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()

drawGameState()```
````

Answer (score 0):

Your main should call drawGameState and it shouldn't be called outside the main

```
def main():
    p.init()
    screen = p.display.set_mode((WIDTH, HEIGHT))
    clock = p.time.Clock()
    screen.fill(p.Color("white"))
    gs = ChessEngine.GameState()
    print(gs.board)
    load_images()  # only operated once
    running = True
    while running:
        for e in p.event.get():
            if e.type == p.QUIT:
                running = False
            drawGameState((screen, gs))
            clock.tick(MAX_FPS)
            p.display.flip()
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to call `drawGameState()` in the application loop instead of the end of the application:

```py
def main():
    # [...]
    
    while running:
        for e in p.event.get():
            if e.type == p.QUIT:
                running = False
       
        drawGameState(screen, gs)       # <--- INSERT
        p.display.flip()
        clock.tick(MAX_FPS)

# [...]

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()

# drawGameState()                        <--- DELETE
```